# Program returns only last line

Tags: c, for-loop

I have written the following simple program. There is a problem present in it because the program returns only the last line. I can't figure out why this happens. Would somebody please help me understand?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[200];
    int i=0, k;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin)){
        i++;
    }

        for(k=0; k<i; k++){
            makeLower(line);
            printf("%s", line);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is only one `line`, which you constantly overwrite. If you want to process each line, do so _inside_ the `while` loop (straightforward) or keep an array of lines (somewhat fiddly). As is, you only count the lines.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin)){
        i++;
    }

        for(k=0; k<i; k++){
            makeLower(line);
            printf("%s", line);
        }
```

with

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin))
{
    makeLower(line);
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

Or if you want to print all the lines AFTER you've entered them...

```
char all_lines[200][200]; // 200 different strings with 200 chars max in each
int line_count;
for(line_count = 0; fgets(all_lines[line_count], 200, stdin); line_count++) {};
for(i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
{
    makeLower(all_lines[i]);
    printf("%s",all_lines[i]);
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have another problem. What if i have switch statmet with multiple of switches?

Comment: Your English does not seem to be that comprehensible, but that's fine. I suggest you edit your current question or make a new one.